# get a count of array property values in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, distinct-values

Given data like

```
[
    { _id:1, data:["abc", "def", "hij", "klm", "nop"]},
    { _id:2, data:["abc", "def", "hij"]},
    { _id:3, data:["abc", "hij"]},
    { _id:4, data:["abc", "def", "hij", "klm", "nop"]},
    { _id:5, data:["def", "hij", "klm"]},
]
```

I am trying to get a query result like

```
[
    { "abc": 4 },
    { "def": 4 },
    { "hij": 5 },
    { "klm": 3 },
    { "nop": 2 },
]
```

where the number is the count of each data property array string value.

I have been working on it from an aggregate pipeline approach, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Comment: Is that data available in `javascript`? would you accept an answer using javascript's array methods?

Comment: I have been working on constructing the query in the mongoDB CLI client, but the end goal environment is a nodejs app.  I am using javascript

Comment: I can only offers a solution where you process the data on the `Javascript` side, but I believe you want it to comes already processed to `Javascript`. Anyway, I suggest to add what you have tried to far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to be able to do this with an aggregation pipeline with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) + [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). For example:

```
db.col.aggregate([{$unwind:"$data"}, {$group: {_id: "$data", data: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : "nop", "data" : 2.0 }
{ "_id" : "abc", "data" : 4.0 }
{ "_id" : "def", "data" : 4.0 }
{ "_id" : "hij", "data" : 5.0 }
{ "_id" : "klm", "data" : 3.0 }
```

Comment: simply exactly.  I found `unwind`'s applicability moments after you posted this answer